# Ancestor Query with Objectify not returning results

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, objectify

I am using objectify 3.1 on appengine and attempting to do a ancestor query.  I want to fetch all the children of an object that are of a certain kind. Below is my code:

```
@Cached
@Entity
public class Car {

 @Id
 @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
 private Long id;

 private String make;
 private String model;
```

}

```
@Cached
@Entity
public class Tire {

@Id
public String keyName; 


@Parent Key<Car> car;

private String brand;
private String size;
```

}

My query is this code:

```
        List<Tire> list= ofy.query(Tire.class).ancestor(new    Key<Car(Car.class,carID))).list();
```

When I create the tire objects I use this code to set the relationship:

```
        newTire.setCar(new Key<Car>(Car.class,Car.getID()));
```

I know the Parent relationship is there because I can query for it in the datastore admin and it shows the parent in the decoded entity key:

```
Decoded entity key: Car: id=135172 > Tire: name=myCarUniqueID
```

This query always returns 0 results, and it seems like I have followed all the best practices on the objectify website.  Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What DepartmentPersonnelInfo class has to do with the question? Or is that supposed to be the Tire class?

Comment: Yes, that was suppose to be tire class.  It has been corrected

Comment: There must be something more going on that isn't shown here, because nothing looks wrong in your example (except various typos from hand-typing it).  Try running the equivalent ancestor query in GQL from the datastore admin page.

Comment: This query worked fine:  select * from Tire where ANCESTOR is Key('Car',--carid--)

Comment: I noticed an example on the objectify site that uses .fetch() on the query.  I could not find this in the docs.  What does this do and is it needed?

Comment: Looks like the problem was late night programming :)  The code above works fine.  I was using the wrong id variable and passing in a String id instead of a long...Sorry about that!  stickFigure if you want to post an answer I will give you credit for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code looks ok, so the only thing that might be wrong is a non-existing `carID`.

The [Objectify javadoc](http://objectify-appengine.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/index.html) listed on the site is actually for trunk version which is a forthcoming Objectify 4. What you need to look at is [Objectify 3.1 javadoc](http://objectify-appengine.googlecode.com/svn/tags/3.1/javadoc/index.html): this version has `fetch()` on the query.

Also, `@GeneratedValue` is [not an Objectify annotation](http://objectify-appengine.googlecode.com/svn/tags/3.1/javadoc/com/googlecode/objectify/annotation/package-frame.htmlhttp://).

Comment: The problem was I was passing a String ID instead of a Long ID...problem solved.  So, yes you are correct!